# Python add data to an empty pd.Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm quite new to python, the thing I'm trying to do is get data from an website and add a part of the webpage to and pandas dataframe.

This is the code I got already but I'm getting an error when adding data to the Dataframe.

**The Code I got:**

```
url = 'https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/w/Module:Exchange/Anglerfish/Data'
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

price_data = soup.find_all('span', class_='s1')
df = pd.DataFrame()

for data in price_data:
  a = pd.DataFrame(data.text.split(":")[0],data.text.split(":")[1])
  df.append(a)

print(df)
```

**The Error I'm Getting:**

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-963d51917cf2> in <module>()
 10 
 11 for data in price_data:
---> 12   a = pd.DataFrame(data.text.split(":")[0],data.text.split(":")[1])
 13   df.append(a)
 14 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
507                 )
508             else:
--> 509                 raise ValueError("DataFrame constructor not properly called!")
510 
511         NDFrame.__init__(self, mgr, fastpath=True)

ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

Comment: Hey, I'm a big rs fan!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more research, the best way for me to do it was:

```
#get data from marketwatch

url = 'https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/w/Module:Exchange/Anglerfish/Data'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
price_data = soup.find_all('span', class_='s1')
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['timestamp', 'price'])

for data in price_data:
  df = df.append({'timestamp': data.text.split(":")[0], 'price': data.text.split(":")[1]}, ignore_index=True)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the data structure you get from `data.text.split(":")[0],data.text.split(":")[1]` does not suit what is expected from the function `pd.DataFrame()`. First take a look at the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) of the function to fully understand what is expecting and how to properly pass data to it. You can either pass a **dictionary** with the column name and the values (arrays must be of equal length, or an index should be specified), or **lists/arrays** as [YOBEN_S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7964527/yoben-s) proposed, for example:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'Column_1':data.text.split(":")[0],'Column_2':data.text.split(":")[1]})
```

Since you are dealing with `html` data, you should try a different approach using `pandas.read_html()` which can be read [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html) for more information

Answer (score 0):

Fix your code by

```
pd.DataFrame([[data.text.split(":")[0],data.text.split(":")[1]]])
```